# htaccess Redirect changed param value

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect page by changing the value of *lang* param, but only this one

Example:

```
www.mysite.com/?lang=en to www.mysite.com/lang=eng
www.mysite.com/?lang=en&param=value to www.mysite.com/?lang=eng&param=value
www.mysite.com/subpage/?lang=en&param=value to www.mysite.com/subpage/?lang=eng&param=value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?lang=en(&.*)?\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?lang=eng%1 [NE,L,R]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I resolved using PHP and redirect page with header().